# Python Subprocess returns 'NoneValue' instead of date value

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, subprocess

I have a file with a subprocess which passes a link such as `https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-31986754` to `DateScraper.py`.

In this instance the div being picked up should be:

```
<div class="date date--v2" data-seconds="1426886791" data-datetime="20 March 2015" data-timestamp-inserted="true">20 March 2015</div>
```

`DateScraper.py` is supposed to return a date value which is used at a later point. However, on returning that value (or non value in this case) I'm presented with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScrapeReferences.py", line 32, in <module>
    reader = csv.DictReader(stdout.decode('ascii').splitlines(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I can't see that there's any problem with what is being returned and why the object is of a NoneType...

### Calling File

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["python","DateScraper.py", a["href"]])
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

reader = csv.DictReader(stdout.decode('ascii').splitlines(),
                        delimiter='^', skipinitialspace=True,
                        fieldnames=["publishdate"])

dateString = ""
for row in reader:
    dateString = (str(row))
```

### Called File - DateScraper.py

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



targetArticle = str(sys.argv[1])
session = requests.Session()

if "bbc.co.uk" in targetArticle:
    html = session.post(targetArticle)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

    dateTag = bsObj.find('div', {'class': 'date'})
    dateTagBS = BeautifulSoup(str(dateTag), "html.parser")

    publishdatew = dateTagBS.getText()

    print(publishdate)

else:
    print("1999-01-01")
```

Comment: The most probable cause is that `dateTag` was not found. Have you checked if it was found?

Comment: How can I check that it is indeed found? I added the html to the question.

Comment: Check if `dateTag==None`.

Comment: I've set publish date `publishdate = "1999-01-01"` and done the check `if dateTag == None: print(publishdate)` and still have the same error.

Comment: You have many other places where things may go wrong. Make sure that the scrapper displays the right results. If it does, proceed to the caller. In other words, in a complex system you must do much debugging.

Comment: If anyone's interested I ended up changing this implementation from using subprocess to creating an object class which had methods to return the data.